# Divide and draw multiple rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a rectangle like this `Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200);` 
and i want to divide it equaly in 20 rectangles 5X4 (5 Columns, 4 Rows) like this

```
|'''|'''|'''|'''|'''|
|...|...|...|...|...|
|'''|'''|'''|'''|'''|
|...|...|...|...|...|
|'''|'''|'''|'''|'''|
|...|...|...|...|...|
|'''|'''|'''|'''|'''|
|...|...|...|...|...|
```

Cn anyone help? Ive been trying solve this for like an hour :(

Comment: No inside a panel, winforms

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I just want to draw 20 smaller rectangles, inside another rectangle, thats it. Im creating a custom control, i cant use DataGridView

Comment: Please post an image of what you need. It's unclear what the output should look like. Maybe you can use GDI+ drawing or even a `TableLayoutPanel`, but first you should share an image of what you need also the usage of those rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

Given your rectangle:

```
    Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200);
```

This will get a list of subrectangles:

```
    List<RectangleF> GetSubRectangles(Rectangle rect, int cols, int rows)
    {
        List<RectangleF> srex = new List<RectangleF>();
        float w = 1f * rect.Width / cols;
        float h = 1f * rect.Height / rows;

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
                srex.Add(new RectangleF(w*c, h*r, w,h ));
        return srex;
    }
```

Note that is returns `RectangleF` not `Rectangle` to avoid loss of precision. When you need a `Rectangle` you can always get one like this:

```
 Rectangle rec = Rectangle.Round(srex[someIndex]);
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

To create a list of 20 rectangles (like you want it) you could use this:

```
List<Rectangle> list = new List<Rectangle>();
int maxWidth = 300;
int maxHeight = 200;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
while (list.Count < 20)
{
    for (x = 0; x < maxWidth; x += (maxWidth / 5))
    {
        for (y = 0; y < maxHeight; y += (maxHeight / 4))
        {
            list.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, (maxWidth / 5), (maxHeight / 4));
        }
        y = 0;
    }
    x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution also works, but im trying to use as few loops as posible.